# Codesigning and notarizing executable file for OSX

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate, notarize

I'm trying to codesign + notarize from the command line a small executable file generated out of a javascript file without success. This file is a very simple CLI tool, aimed to be used through the mac's terminal.

downloading the file and attempting to run it results in the error:

[image]

> "testBinaryFile can’t be opened because the identity of the developer
> cannot be confirmed."

(and running it from the terminal, as it should be, results in a "killed" status on the process").

These are the steps that I did:
0. bundling the code into an executable (named `testBinaryFile`)

1. Codesigning the executable with:

```
codesign -s CERTIFICATE_UUID --timestamp -o runtime -v testBinaryFile --force
```

2. zipping the executable (so it can be uploaded for notarization):

```
ditto -c -k testBinaryFile testBinaryFile.zip
```

3. sending the zip for notarization:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app \
    --primary-bundle-id io.test.bundled \
    --username <OUR_APPLE_ID> \
    --password <OUR_APPLE_APP_SPECIFIC_PASS> \
    --file testBinaryFile.zip
```

4. polling service until we get back a success notarization message with:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-info REQUEST_ID -u <OUR_APPLE_ID> -p <OUR_APPLE_APP_SPECIFIC_PASS>
```

5. Uploading the zip file to our hosting in Github (also tried on Google's hosting services)
6. Downloading the zip file, extracting it, and trying to run it -> results in the error attached above.

other notes:
*I have an "Apple Developer ID certificate" that allows distributing the bundled executable outside of the AppStore.

*I use the same bundled executable inside a notarized .dmg installer containing ".app” application (and the bundle inside its /resources), and there I manage to use it without any issues at all

Any clues on how to make it work also just for the bundle?

Comment: You do not mean the word bundle here, you mean compile.  To bundle is to place the compiled executable in my.app/Contents/MacOS/binaryexecutive

Answer (score 2):

have you resolved this issue? I currently have the same problem. I think the problem is that even the executable is signed and notarized, when running check of the notarization result on it: `spctl -a -t exec -vvv macos/bw` I got:

```
macos/bw: rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)
origin=Developer ID Application: <cert name redacted>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use certificates from third-party providers (eg Comodo, DigiCert) because such certificates will not pass Gatekeeper which requires an Apple developer issued certificate.

Comment: I meant "3rd party" as a certificate that allows to ship the product outside of the app store (like a 3rd party :) )

Comment: You mean "Developer ID Application" certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Your gatekeeper security settings is disallowing this because it is not even an app. It may have been quarantined as a result, meaning you would have to run `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file` to get it to run.
The less preferred method is to lower your security settings.

- Also note that because the notarization ticket cannot be stapled to the binary executable, the user would require internet to access the ticket in order to enable code execution.